# Как адаптировать видео под мобильные устройства

Tags: html, css, iframe

Я вставил код видео с одного видеопортала на сайт. Все бы хорошо, вот только на мобильных устройствах видеозапись отображается СЛИШКОМ громоздкой, можно ли сделать так, что бы на компьютере и на мобильных устройствах видео отображалось разного размера.
Может, размер как-нибудь в css можно изменить?

Код:

```
<iframe width="640" height="384" src="//video.sibnet.ru/shell.php?videoid=3291274" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрать инлайн стили, и управлять `CSS`, при таком подходе придется с высотой повозиться на `media запросах`

```css
.video iframe {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  height: 380px;
}

@media(max-width: 680px) {
  .video iframe {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 4800px) {
  .video iframe {
    height: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
<iframe src="//video.sibnet.ru/shell.php?videoid=3291274" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Адаптивное видео (css из html следует перенести куда следует, кусок кода взял из результата работы своего js скрипта):

```html
<div style="padding-top: 5px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; max-width: 640px;">
  <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 0px; padding-bottom: 56.25%;">
    <iframe src="https://video.sibnet.ru/shell.php?videoid=3291274/" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** Тут отказывается работать, смотреть демо следует на https://jsfiddle.net/z9xyprht/ (там и ширину окна можно мышкой поменять).